# Processing: add method from another class

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to build graph on processing. I built the "Node" class, and I would like to create 'addNode' method on "Graph" class .
the problem is I do not know how to set the add method.

the error showed the function "add()" accepts parameters like "add(int Node)"

here is my code,

```
public class Graph{

    ArrayList<Node> node = new ArrayList<Node>(); 

 public Graph(ArrayList<Node> node){

  this.node = node;

  }

  void addNode(Node c, Node x, Node y, Node r, Node col){

    this.node.add(c,x,y,r,col);

   }  
 }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) doesn't support adding multiple object of same type in one go and that's the reason you are getting compile time error. You need to add them one by one as below:

```
void addNode(Node c, Node x, Node y, Node r, Node col){
    this.node.add(c);
    this.node.add(x);
    this.node.add(y);
    this.node.add(r);
    this.node.add(col);
}
```

You could add contents all together in one line as below:

```
void addNode(Node c, Node x, Node y, Node r, Node col){
    this.node.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Node[] {c,x,y,r,col}))
}
```

Remember here you are creating a temp array and then a list.